# Hide the "Create" Button in a specific module only in odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

i want to hide the create and import button in the header of my treeview my Odoo version is odoo11

[image: screen shot of my treeview]

I tried using the inserting `create="false" edit="false"` in my treeview tag but it hides all the button and I also tried replacing the `t-operation="after"` to `t-operation="replace"` but it affects all the other application

```
<template xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
            <t  t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="replace">
                <button t-if="widget.modelName == 'hr.timeinout'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_refresh_button" accesskey="f">
                    Refresh List
                </button> 
            </t>
        </t>
</template>
```

I only want to hide the "Create" and "Import" button in that specific treeview thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code to remove the create button:

```xml
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <!-- this will hide create button for model  'hr.timeinout' -->
        <t  t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-if">widget.modelName != 'hr.timeinout'</attribute>
        </t>

        <!-- this will add refresh button for model  'hr.timeinout' -->
        <t  t-jquery="div.o_list_buttons" t-operation="prepend">
            <button t-if="widget.modelName == 'hr.timeinout'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary oe_refresh_button" accesskey="f">
                Refresh List
            </button>
        </t>

    </t>
```

And to remove the import button for this model:

```xml
    <t t-extend="ImportView.import_button">
        <!-- this will remove button import for model  'hr.timeinout' -->
        <t  t-jquery="button.o_button_import" t-operation="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-if">widget.modelName != 'hr.timeinout'</attribute>
        </t>
    </t>
```